# Does enable_shared_from_this and make_shared provide the same optimization

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, make-shared

As I understand `make_shared<T>(...)` may provide some memory allocation optimization (it may allocate reference counter within same memory block as instance of class T).

Do enable_shared_from_this provides the same optimization? So:

```
class T : std::enable_shared_from_this<T> {};
...
auto t = std::shared_ptr<T>(new T);
```

Is the same as:

```
class T {};
...
auto t = std::make_shared<T>();
```

If not take in account sizeof(T).

Comment: The two are completely orthogonal. `enable_shared_from_this` is relevant when you *already have* a shared pointer.

Comment: @KerrekSB I suppose that enable_shared_from_this adds some data to the class that can be used by shared pointer implementation. As for me the simplest way - is to place number of references as part of enable_shared_from_this and this may help to reduce memory allocations in the first case.

Comment: I'm tempted to say "yes", as otherwise there's no way to retrieve the refcount block from inside the object. But that's just a hunch.

Comment: I don't understand the confusion: you make a shared pointer with either `p = make_shared<T>()` or `p = shared_ptr<T>(new T())`. Either way, you can then say `p->shared_from_this()` to get another share.

Comment: `enable_shared_from_this` allow to "retrieve" a `shared_ptr` from an instance (owned by `shared_ptr`).

Comment: @KerrekSB The question is not about how to retrieve shared pointer. The question about memory allocations optimization.

Comment: @DmitryPoroh: Yes, and I'm saying that the memory optimization is unrelated to `enable_shared_from_this`. With `make_shared` you have a single allocation, and with `shared_ptr<T>(new T)` you have two separate allocations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Do enable_shared_from_this provides the same optimization? So:

No. As you can see from the wording in the standard, `enable_shared_from_this<T>` has a `weak_ptr<T>` data member. That adds a `weak_ptr<T>` to the class, which has a pointer to the control block that contains the reference counts. It doesn't contain the reference counts directly. The control block containing the reference counts still exists external to the object.

The control block containing the reference counts must outlive the object, so that other `weak_ptr` objects that used to refer to the object can still access the control block, to check whether it has expired.

If the control block was inside the object it would be destroyed when the object was destroyed, and it would not be possible for a dangling `weak_ptr` to safely determine if the object had expired. In theory the memory of the control block could remain allocated and still be used and the reference counts updated, even though the object they were part of was destroyed, but that seems pretty ugly (and it would mean the object would not be destroyed with `delete`, it would require an explicit destructor call and explicit `operator delete` call to free the memory).

You also couldn't use the embedded control block if the owning `shared_ptr`  was created with a custom deleter or custom allocator, because the size of those objects would not be known in advance. In such cases you'd still need to allocate an external control block *in addition to* the one embeded in the `enable_shared_from_this<T>` base class, wasting even more space.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation!

Comment: It's quite an interesting question, but the more I think about how it would work the more complications I find.

Comment: I suppose in case of make_shared  memory of  instance also couldn't be freed until last weak_ptr points to the control block. But in contrast with enable_shared_from_this  it could be clearly implemented from C++ language point (don't use destroyed object).

Comment: And problem became more complex if take in account overloaded new/delete :)

Comment: Yes, with `make_shared` the memory is not freed until the last weak reference is dropped. But that's OK, because `make_shared` controls both the allocation+construction and destruction+deallocation, so can do it all correctly. With `shared_ptr<X>(new X)` the object should be destroyed with `delete`, but that would prevent the control block from outliving the object (because the memory would be deallocated as soon as the destructor runs).